# Resolved : Faillure to load dll in cpp

Tags: c++, dll

I have a cpp dll that i am trying to import to my qt cpp project, usig the function LoadLibrary, the fubnction returns NULL, I am asking for the reason of that ?,
the architecture of the DLL file is x86, while the application that i am develepping in x64, can that be a reason of failure, and do you have any suggestion how to fix this issue ?

Comment: That's the problem, you have to load matching architectures. To fix it, you need an x64 build of the DLL.

Comment: yes, i recompiled my dll in x64 architecture, and the problem is fixed

Answer (score 2):

> the architecture of the DLL file is x86, while the application that i am develepping in x64

You cannot load libraries of a different architecture into your process.

> do you have any suggestion how to fix this issue

There are many ways to work around this, anything from recompiling your DLL to the proper architecture, or if you can't then create a proxy process of the secondary architecture and then use some form of IPC (mailslots, pipes, sockets, shared memory) to proxy calls into the DLL and marshal results back out.